# Using the same event multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know whether it is possible to use the same event multiple times. I have an comboBox  and when item A is selected, I only want the user to enter digits. On the other hand, if the user selects item B, I want to permit the user to enter only letters instead in the same textbox. I'm using the "PreviewTextInput" event and know how to make those restrictions such as:

```
 private void textBoxKun_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
```

but how can I implement the functionality i want ?.

Comment: "event" is different object from what you describe in post (what you talk is "event handler"). But even ignoring that it is not clear what you have problem with. I.e. do you know about `if` statement?

Comment: Why do you need to use the same event handler multiple times? From the look of it, you just need to check in your `PreviewTextInput` function which restrictions you need to have on the entered text.

Comment: Sounds like you just use a different RegEx based on what is selected in the Combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems simple enough, I'll venture an answer. Note that your question is incomplete. You really need to specify what item A and B are.

```
private void textBoxKun_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = null;
    if ( A.isChecked ) {
        regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
    } else {
        regex = new Regex("[^A-Za-z]+");
    }
    e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

Comment: How couldn't I think that it was so basic. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the feature you are seeking for seems to be the "if" keyword ;)

Just check the SelectedValue (or SelectedItem, or SelectedText according your needs) of your combo to see if it is A or B, and do the proper thing according it.

```
if (combo.SelectedText == "A")
   dosomething();
else if (combo.SelectedText == "B")
   dosomethingelse();
```

in your event.

If I misunderstood the question, please explain it better...